# Current user is the previous one when logout and login again

Tags: authentication, flutter

I am trying to resolve this issue, the first time I login in my app, everything is ok, **but when I logout and login again**, the current user (retrieved from parse) is the previous one. If I call again for the current user in another widget, the current user is the correct one, but not in the beginning.

I think that the **logout method** is the correct one because, as I explained before, in other widgets later in the app, the current user is the right one.

```
static Future<void> logOut() async {
    ParseUser currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser();
    ParseResponse userResponse =
        await ParseUser.getCurrentUserFromServer(currentUser.sessionToken);
    ParseUser user = userResponse.result as ParseUser;
    await user.logout(deleteLocalUserData: true);
  }
```

This is the **login method**

```
Future<ParseResponse> login() async {
    try {
      final Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = <String, String>{
        keyVarUsername: username,
        keyVarPassword: password
      };

      final Uri url = getSanitisedUri(_client, '$keyEndPointLogin',
          queryParams: queryParams);
      _saveChanges();
      final Response response =
          await _client.get(url, headers: <String, String>{
        keyHeaderRevocableSession: '1',
      });

      return await _handleResponse(
          this, response, ParseApiRQ.login, _debug, parseClassName);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      return handleException(e, ParseApiRQ.login, _debug, parseClassName);
    }
  }
```

This is the **class that appears just after the login is completed and where i try to retrieve the current user**, achieving the **previous user**.

```
class UserInterfaceAppPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _UserInterfaceAppPageState createState() => _UserInterfaceAppPageState();
}

class _UserInterfaceAppPageState extends State<UserInterfaceAppPage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[];
  Future<SharedPreferences> pref;
  Future<bool> dishes;

  _UserInterfaceAppPageState() {
    initState();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    dishes = DbHelper.insertDishes();

    Future<User> _currentUser = ParseManager().getActualUser();
```

This is the **getActualUser() method** where I retrieve the current user.

```
Future<User> getActualUser() async {
    ParseUser currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser();
    ParseResponse userResponse =
        await ParseUser.getCurrentUserFromServer(currentUser.sessionToken);
    ParseUser user = userResponse.result as ParseUser;

    User actualUser = User.fromParse(user);

    return actualUser;
  }
```

Please, let me know if you need more information of any method or class in my app.
I tried so many things, included updating the SDK but i have the latest version and I could not find a similar issue.

Finally this is the **output of flutter doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale es-ES)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] VS Code (version 1.43.0)
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 1):

The list where I was storing my widgets was static, so the data never destroys until i killed the app.

```
static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[];
```

Solution: Remove static from the widgets list

```
List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[];
```